# Messages unflagged in Mail.app remain flagged in Outlook

Tags: mail.app, macos, ms-office

When I flag a message in Mail.app (9.3 running on El Cap 10.11.6) on an Office365 account it also gets flagged in Outlook (15.25, also on El Cap).

However when I un-flag it in Mail.app this information does not propagate to Outlook. In the Outlook web app it *does* get un-flagged.

Is there any way to get this working so the message also gets un-flagged in Outlook?